# 600+ warnings on TesseractOCRiOS Framework as of Xcode9. Is there anyone else having the same issue?

Tags: ios, tesseract, xcode9

I was following this rather recent [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTQ1z_8KXZo&lc=z13tdfeatneahdzcg224g3hzqnrfsvfyh04.1489381330049240) from Youtube on how to implement Tesseract for iOS apps. I am getting about 604 warnings on top of the framework alone, most of them related to documentation. Can anyone help explain that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by setting Enable Bitcode = NO in all Projects and Targets for the Workspace.